# bootstrap 4 responsive full screen overlay menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to figure out a way to combine an animated hamburger menu in bootstrap 4 with a full screen menu overlay. Problem: when I set data-toggle="modal" on the button, I get the modal overlay but the animation of the collapsed hamburger menu ("X") in the background (i.e. underneath the overlay) becomes inactive.

On the other hand, when I replace the "modal" attribute with "collapse", the hamburger animation works fine but the overlay menu does not appear.

Is there a simple way to combine these two functions?

This is the CSS:

```css
body {
  padding-top: 5rem;
  margin: 0;
  background: url(../assets/original/test.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.base-layout {
  padding: 3rem 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Navbar responsive toggler + hamburger animation */

.navbar-toggler {
  border: none;
  background: transparent !important;
  float: left !important;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.navbar-toggler:focus {
  outline: none;
  background: transparent !important;
}

.navbar-toggler .icon-bar {
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0px, 0px);
  transition: ease all .2s;
}

.navbar-toggler .icon-bar {
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 1px;
}

.navbar-toggler .icon-bar+.icon-bar {
  margin-top: 4px;
}


/*.icon-bar:nth-child(2) {
      width: 16px;
      transition: ease all .2s;
    }*/

.navbar-toggler:hover>.icon-bar:nth-child(2) {
  width: 22px;
  transition: ease all .2s;
}

.navbar-toggler:active>.icon-bar:nth-child(2) {
  width: 22px;
  transition: ease all .2s;
}

.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed) .icon-bar:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5px, 4px);
  transition: ease all .2s;
}

.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed) .icon-bar:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease all .2s;
}

.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed) .icon-bar:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(4px, -4px);
  transition: ease all .2s;
}


/* Modal */

.modal-nav-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.modal-nav-body {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.modal-nav-body ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.modal-nav-body ul li {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 130%;
  padding: 8px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

This is the HTML code:
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-transparent fixed-top">

    <span class="navbar-brand" href="#"></span>

    <!-- data-toggle="modal" :: COLLAPSE -->
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler collapsed btn-open" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nav-modal" aria-controls="nav-modal" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      </button>

  </nav>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="nav-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-nav-content">
        <div class="modal-nav-body">
          <ul class="wrap-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav menu item #1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav menu item #2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav menu item #3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav menu item #4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <main role="main" class="container">
    <div class="base-layout text-white text-left">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p class="lead">Lead text...</p>
    </div>
  </main>


  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: What's the logic behind combining a hamburger menu and a modal? They are mutually exclusive

Comment: I am sorry if the initial explanation was not clear, I updated the question. I am simply trying to keep the hamburger menu icon animated when there is an overlay. This is fairly standard and can be seen on many mobile navigation menus but I am new to bootstrap ...

Comment: To me, a menu would be inactive and not directly clickable if there is a modal shown. Is what you want to achieve is a sidebar that expands (with a hamburger button), that 'grays out' the rest of the website?

Comment: This is an approximate example what I am trying to achieve [https://codepen.io/riogrande/pen/gbXxdx/]. Basically, the user clicks the hamburger menu, the three horizontal bars collapse to an X, and the overlay is displayed with the menu items. Then, to close the menu, the user can click on the X, the overlay closes and the menu icon reverts back to a regular three-line hamburger.

Comment: A few solutions to this were provided on this other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46910741/creating-a-bootstrap-navbar-collapse-overlay-menu